# How to calculate 95% confidence interval for a proportion in R?

Tags: r, probability, sampling, confidence-interval

Assume I own a factory that produces 150 screws a day and there is a 22% error rate. Now I am going to estimate how many screws are faulty each day for a year (365 days) with

```
    rbinom(n = 365, size = 150, prob = 0.22)
```

which generates 365 values in this way

```
45 31 35 31 34 37 33 41 37 37 26 32 37 38 39 35 44 36 25 27 32 25 30 33 25 37 36 31 32 32 43 42 32 33 33 38 26 24 ...................
```

Now for each of the value generated, I am supposed to calculate a 95% confidence interval for the proportion of faulty screws in each day.

I am not sure how I can do this. Is there any built in functions for this (I am not supposed to use any packages) or should I create a new function?

Comment: That's not how a CI works, the CI is on the mean, not on individual observations. What exactly is your goal?

Comment: See CRAN package [`binom`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=binom), function `binom.confint`.

Comment: @user2974951 he has multiple observations, namely 150 each day. Of which there are 45 faulty on day one.

Comment: This sounds like a home work question. Is this something you have to calculate yourself or are you supposed to use a function from base r for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of trials per day is large enough and the probability of failure not too extreme, then you can use the normal approximation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval.

```
# number of failures, for each of the 365 days
f <- rbinom(365, size = 150, prob = 0.22)

# failure rates
p <- f/150

# confidence interval for the failur rate, for each day
p + 1.96*sqrt((p*(1-p)/150))
p - 1.96*sqrt((p*(1-p)/150))
```